# Install Linux Mint Cinnamon's polished Ctrl+R/"reverse-i-search" on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, bash-history

In Mint, when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in any terminal, you get a pretty nice UI for the reverse-i-search.

*(To clarify - I'm referring to the extra polish provided in Mint - the UI is a step above the basic history search that I'm used to in Ubuntu and other distros)*

I'd like this on my Ubuntu boxes.

I'm not sure if it's a Mint feature or a Cinnamon feature, or some third party tool that can be installed.

Googling for it has returned nothing... is there a way to install this feature on Ubuntu?

Mint:

[image]

Ubuntu/other:

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running (and what flavour)?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what does reverse-i-search do exactly?

Comment: @JacobVlijm it is a bash feature for all I know and has nothing to do with Mint. see `man readline` :) Oh and `reverse-i-search` is actually `control-r` it seems.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/583568/3701431

Comment: @JacobVlijm there were replies in the comments yesterday which were cleared out by a mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something similar for Bash / Zsh: [hstr](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr);

Once installed, hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> should bring up this GUI:

[image: s1]

To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hh
```

I'm unable to test it personally as I'm on Wily and there are no packages for Wily on the repository yet, however there are packages available for Precise up to Vidid.

Answer (score 2):

In Zsh you can get something similar with [Zsh Navigation Tools](https://github.com/psprint/zsh-navigation-tools);

Once installed, hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will bring up this GUI:

[image: s1]

Typing a partial command will shrink the list:

[image: s2]

Hitting <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> will allow to skim through the shrinked list and select a command:

[image: s5]

Hittin <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will write the selected command to the prompt:

[image: s5]

You can install Zsh Navigation Tools by running this command (it will backup your current `~/.zshrc` to `~/.zshrc.bak` if present):

```
cp ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrc.bak; sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/psprint/zsh-navigation-tools/master/doc/install.sh)"
```

Zsh Navigation Tools will be installed at `~/.config/znt/zsh-navigation-tools` and its configuration files will be installed at `~/.config/znt`.

Answer (score 1):

It's fzf and it works exactly like on yours screenshot
https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Comment: Hey azeos! Please make sure that your answer is detailed (use the [edit] feature).